# How to send nessage to a client in netty

Tags: netty

I am a Netty beginner and struggling to manage client list. I save device ID and divice name when a client connects and when a different client wants to send a message to the client by device ID, how can I handle this? I have seen the examples how to use ChannelGroup to save the connected clients. But it is only for channel and it has attributeKey but it is for different purpose. Do I just map or list instead of ChannelGroup? Is there any good idea?
Your answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just implement your own ChannelGroup that stores the clients differently and lets you find a client by ID. But since you only want to relay a message to ONE connected client I don't see much sense in using a group. As far as I understand ChannelGroups are supposed to make broadcast messages easier.
I think a simple HashMap with the ID as key would be enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am thinking ChannelGrop for just future purpose.

Comment: Could you explain more "I think a simple HashMap with the ID as key would be enough."? HashMap will store an object which includes ID and what? ChannelHandlerContext or something else?

Comment: `HashMap<String, Channel> channelMap` for example. If you want to send it to a single client, you retrieve the according channel from the map and just `writeAndFlush`

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` would be better