# How to manage list of clients to send data in netty

Tags: java, sockets, netty, tcp

A similar question might have been asked, but indeed it is a different question:
[How to send nessage to a client in netty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134078/how-to-send-nessage-to-a-client-in-netty)

I just have started Netty and asynchronous I/O.

I want to map clients by a String. When a client connected to my server sends its ID-String and i want to save that String with that client's Socket/Channel into a map. After that when i want to send any message to the Client, get that client's Socket/Channel from map by ID and send it.

Is it possible to implement it myself in this way: 
Create my ClientData class with variables ID-String and ChannelHandlerContext object.

In ChannelHandler channelRead method add to map, and remove from map somewhere else.

Or is there any other way in Netty? What do you recommend for this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this should like something you could do. Like having a ConcurrentMap and just lookup stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Norman.. But i couldn't make the implementation above. 

in ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter I've:

 public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)

Actually i didn't understand what is msg type? I tried to cast to String but it isn't a String.

Which example of netty is best for my implementation? ChatServer?

Comment: Type of msg depends on what the client sends. Does your client send strings?

Comment: It is "String" and i've used "channelRead0" (netty4) method in telnet example. That is OK for me. Thx :)